# Make a div able to display bold words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering why if I set something bold in my textarea, Then when I copy it in my div it shows `<b>word</b>` instead of **word**.

I wrote that if you set a word in bold with the button, it is displayed in bold in the textarea. Then if you press the button "OK", is displayed also in a new div but not in bold.

How can I show the word in bold hiding the code?

My code:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfamqvub/5/)

Html:

```
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here Guys</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
<button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text"><b>B</b>
    </button>

<div id='boxes'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#faketxt {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

.fakes{
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  display:inline-block;
}

#boxes{
  display : flex;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var wordLimit = 145;
  var words = primo.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
  if (words.length) {
    var count = 0;
    var div = createDiv();
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
      }
      if (div.innerHTML) {
        div.append(' ');
      }
      div.append(word);
    });
  }
});

function createDiv() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'fakes';
  document.getElementById('boxes').append(div);
  return div;
}
```

Comment: This is the content of `words` after splitting the content of `primo` -> `words = ["Write", "<b>Here", "</b>Guys"]`

Comment: and? What do you mean?

Comment: My guess it that the content is not escaped properly. Are you looking for a jQuery or a pure javascript solution?

Comment: @Andreas How can i fix it?

Comment: @Bingla jQuery solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this solution can be considered acceptable. 
Anyway:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var wordLimit = 145;
  var toWrite = $('#faketxt').html();
  var words = primo.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig, "").split(/\s/);
  if (words.length) {
    var count = 0;
    var div = createDiv();
    var bold = false;
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
      }
      if (div.innerHTML) {
        div.append(' ');
      }

      if (word.indexOf('<b>') != -1) {
        bold = true;
      }

      if (bold) {
        $(div).html($(div).html() + '<b>' +
          word + '</b>');
      } else {
        $(div).html($(div).html() +
          word);
      }

      if (word.indexOf('</b>') != -1) {
        bold = false;
      }
    });
  }
});

function createDiv() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'fakes';
  document.getElementById('boxes').append(div);
  return div;
}
```

```css
#faketxt {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  width: 400px;
}
.fakes {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here Guys</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
<button onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" class="fontStyle" title="Bold Highlighted Text"><b>B</b>
</button>

<div id='boxes'>
```

Comment: Why do you think that could be not considered acceptible?

Comment: Because it doesn't "build" the div content inside the loop. Instead it saves the html beforehand and then copies it inside the div.

Comment: Can you do it with the loop? Whitout changing this mechanism? Because if I set the world limit to 1, I want to display 3 divs in this case (the case with 3 words)...

Comment: This appends the word to the element. Don't know if it's acceptable. $(div).html( $(div).html() + word );

Comment: It doesn't seem to work properly. The bold markup breaks after the first word.

Comment: @noise There is a way to fix it?

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi I partially fixed the snippet above to build the div text inside the loop. It only works for full words (for example "Write H<b>ere Guys</b>" becomes "Write <b>Here</b><b>Guys</b>", including the "H " that shouldn't be in bold).

Comment: @noise Why in this case the position of the divs isn't right? https://jsfiddle.net/wfamqvub/8/

Comment: I think this is the fix you need (adding float:left; to your divs css): https://jsfiddle.net/x2m5gque/

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about building only one string and then append it instead of appending each word inside the forEach.
For example by concatenating the string like this:
...

```
var newHtml = "";
words.forEach(function(word) {
    if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
    }
    if(newHtml !== ""){
        newHtml += ' ';
    }
    newHtml += word;
});
$(div).append(newHtml);
```

...
After append by default the tag  will be close automatically.

Comment: If i set the limit of words to 1, it doesn't work, look: https://jsfiddle.net/wfamqvub/7/

Comment: Yes it works, the problem there is another no related with the string bold.
Check the conditional and where and when you call createDiv function.